# Pulling information and comparing it with a CSV file

Tags: java, arraylist, comparable

In my assignment, we are supposed to create a ListArray and pull in the info from a CSV file, print out the list, and find the information that the user asked for via scanner and print out the item(s). We have to include:

- `ListArray()` with 10 elements,
- `ListArray( int capacity )`

  - Constructs a list using an array with capacity elements,
- `void add( E item )`

  - Add item to the list,
- `int find( E target )`

  - Find target in the list. If found, return the index (relative 0)
    If not found, return -1.
  - The find() method should use equals() method to compare generic objects as done by the Java ArrayList class.
- `E get( int index )`

  - Return object E at position index in list. If index out of bounds, return null.

So far I have not been able to get it to work but I have gotten to the point where it will print off the list and find the part. Although it iterates over the "Cannot find part" else statement and I am so lost the Hubble cannot find me. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class Prog2<E> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String partNumber = "";
        String description = "";
        double price = 0;
        String warehouseID = "";
        int quantity = 0;

        Scanner part = null;
        try {
            part = new Scanner(new File("parts.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: File was not found");
        }
        System.out.printf("%-13s %-30s %9s %14s %11s\n", " Part Number", "  Description", "  Price", " Warehouse",
                "Quantity");
        System.out.printf("%-13s %-32s %8s    %11s %11s\n", "-------------", " ------------------------", "-------",
                "-----------", "----------");

        ListArray<Part> items = new ListArray<Part>();
        while (part.hasNext()) {
            String partInfo = part.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = partInfo.split(",[ ]*");

            partNumber = tokens[0];
            description = tokens[1];
            price = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
            warehouseID = tokens[3];
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);

            items.add(new Part(partNumber, description, price, warehouseID, quantity));
            System.out.printf("%-14s %-31s %8.2f %14s %11d\n", partNumber, description, price, warehouseID, quantity);
        }
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nEnter any part number.");
        String answer = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).getPartNumber().equals(answer)) {

                System.out.printf("Part Number: %-10s\n", items.get(i).getPartNumber());
                System.out.printf("Description: %-20s\n", items.get(i).getDescription());
                System.out.printf("Price: %-3.2f\n", items.get(i).getPrice());
                System.out.printf("Warehouse: %s\n", items.get(i).getWarehouseID());
                System.out.printf("Quantity: %d\n", items.get(i).getQuantity());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Unable to locate part. Please try again.");
            }
        }
        part.close();
    }

}

public class Part implements Comparable {

    private String partNumber;
    private String description;
    private double price;
    private String warehouseID;
    private int quantity;

    public Part(String partNumber, String description, double price, String warehouseID, int quantity) {
        super();
        this.partNumber = partNumber;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.warehouseID = warehouseID;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getPartNumber() {
        return partNumber;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getWarehouseID() {
        return warehouseID;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object args) {
        return this.partNumber.compareTo(((Part) args).partNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object t) {
        if (this == t) {
            return true;
        }
        if (t == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != t.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Part other = (Part) t;
        if (partNumber == null) {
            if (other.partNumber != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!partNumber.equals(other.partNumber)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}

public class ListArray<E extends Comparable> {

    private E[] list;
    private int size;

    public ListArray() {
        super();
        list = (E[]) new Comparable[13];
        size = 0;
    }

    public void add(E item) {
        if (size >= list.length) {

        }
        list[size] = item;
        size++;
    }

    public void add(int index, E item) {
        int pos = size - 1;
        while (pos > index) {
            list[pos + 1] = list[pos];
            pos--;
        }
        list[index] = item;
        size++;
    }

    public E get(int index) {
        return list[index];
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public Object indexOf(Part target) {
        int index = 0;
        while (list[index].equals(target) != true && index < size) {
            index++;
        }
        if (list[index].equals(target)) {
            return (int) list[index];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I think it is an issue with my Comparable; however, I am at a loss why it keeps printing out the cannot find. I have not been able figure out a find that works either which could be my issue as well.

Comment: example of an entry line in the csv file?

Comment: Does this code even compile or run on your machine? I cannot seem to compile it without changing the code.

Comment: When posting a question, please exclude extraneous information and attach related data, like cucaracho mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are printing `Unable to locate part. Please try again.` whenever you come across one part in your list that does not match the given part number. As such, you need to set a flag that stores whether you've found the part or not. Only after the loop will you be able to determine whether you've found the part or not.

```java
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    if (items.get(i).getPartNumber().equals(answer)) {
        System.out.printf("Part Number: %-10s\n", items.get(i).getPartNumber());
        System.out.printf("Description: %-20s\n", items.get(i).getDescription());
        System.out.printf("Price: %-3.2f\n", items.get(i).getPrice());
        System.out.printf("Warehouse: %s\n", items.get(i).getWarehouseID());
        System.out.printf("Quantity: %d\n", items.get(i).getQuantity());

        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Unable to locate part. Please try again.");
}
```

Sidenote: please include the associated data next time you ask a question on StackOverflow; it was rather difficult reverse-engineering your code! Nonetheless, welcome to the community!

Answer (score 0):

sorry about forgetting to add the data. When we went over this later my issue was with the Boolean equals method. It was causing an issue with grabbing the correct information. I am going to include my finished and working code for anyone who is having a similar issue. I will also include a sample of the CSV file. Again, sorry for not getting back that quick and not adding pertinent data for the question. `public class Prog2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String partNumber = "";
    String description = "";
    double price = 0;
    String warehouseID = "";
    int quantity = 0;

    Scanner part = null;
    try {
        part = new Scanner(new File("parts.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: File was not found");
    }
    System.out.printf("%-13s %-30s %9s %14s %11s\n", " Part Number", "  Description", "  Price", " Warehouse",
            "Quantity");
    System.out.printf("%-13s %-32s %8s    %11s %11s\n", "-------------", " ------------------------", "-------",
            "-----------", "----------");
    /**
     * List array is created
     */
    ListArray<Part> items = new ListArray<Part>();
    while (part.hasNext()) {
        String partInfo = part.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = partInfo.split(",[ ]*");

        partNumber = tokens[0];
        description = tokens[1];
        price = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
        warehouseID = tokens[3];
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);

        items.add(new Part(partNumber, description, price, warehouseID, quantity));
        System.out.printf("%-14s %-31s %8.2f %14s %11d\n", partNumber, description, price, warehouseID, quantity);
    }

    /**
     * Scanner is created to get user input to compare to parts.txt
     */
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nEnter any part number.");
    String answer = in.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        Part search = new Part(answer);
        int index = items.find(search);
        if (items.get(i).getPartNumber().equals(answer)) {

            System.out.printf("Part Number: %-10s\n", items.get(i).getPartNumber());
            System.out.printf("Description: %-20s\n", items.get(i).getDescription());
            System.out.printf("Price: %-3.2f\n", items.get(i).getPrice());
            System.out.printf("Warehouse: %s\n", items.get(i).getWarehouseID());
            System.out.printf("Quantity: %d\n", items.get(i).getQuantity());
        }
        part.close();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Part implements Comparable {
private String partNumber;
private String description;
private double price;
private String warehouseID;
private int quantity;

public Part(String partNumber, String description, double price, String warehouseID, int quantity) {
    super();
    this.partNumber = partNumber;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.warehouseID = warehouseID;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public Part(String partNumber) {
    super();
    this.partNumber = partNumber;
}

public String getPartNumber() {
    return partNumber;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public String getWarehouseID() {
    return warehouseID;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object args) {
    return this.partNumber.compareTo(((Part) args).partNumber);
}
```

}

```
public class ListArray<E extends Comparable> {
private E[] list;
private int size;

/**
 * Constructor for the class List array
 */
public ListArray() {
    super();
    list = (E[]) new Comparable[13];
    size = 0;
}

public void add(E item) {
    if (size >= list.length) {
        E[] expansion = (E[]) new Comparable[size + 10];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            expansion[i] = list[i];
        }
        list = (E[]) new Comparable[size + 10];
        list = expansion;
    }
    list[size] = item;
    size++;
}

public ListArray(int capacity) {
    super();
    list = (E[]) new Comparable[capacity];
    size = 0;
}

public void add(int index, E item) {
    int pos = size - 1;
    while (pos > index) {
        list[pos + 1] = list[pos];
        pos--;
    }
    list[index] = item;
    size++;
}

public int find(E target) {
    int index = 0;
    while ((list[index].compareTo(target)) != 0 && index < size) {
        index++;
    }
    if (list[index].compareTo(target) == 0) {
        return index;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

public E get(int index) {
    return list[index];
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}

public Object indexOf(Part target) {
    int index = 0;
    while (list[index].equals(target) != true && index < size) {
        index++;
    }
    if (list[index].equals(target)) {
        return (int) list[index];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Here is a sample of the CSV file.

```
12345,Left-Handed Bacon Stretcher,125.95,PGH,2
```